# Filter coefficients hamming window for low-complexity Welch PSD computation

Tags: fft, filters, discrete-signals, power-spectral-density, window-functions

I am trying to implement the proposed method from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TCSI.2013.2264711) <sup>1</sup>, to eventually have a more efficient PSD computation for feature extraction on a microcontroller.
The method is suitable since I am using a hamming window and have 50% overlap in the segments.

In short this method splits the segments in two parts, calculates the FFT for the sub-segments, merges 2 sub-segments and applies the window in the frequency domain.
Then for the next segment, it can reuse the last sub-segment from the previous calculation as the first sub-segments of the current segment.

To start I am implementing the window functionality in the frequency domain on the 'whole
FFT of the segment'.

To apply the window in the frequency domain, normally you would need to compute the convolution, however the paper states the following:

> The convolution operation is computationally complex compared
> to simple multiplication operation. However, the window
> functions used in the PSD computation typically represent
> raised cosine functions and these can be represented by 3 or 5
> non-zero coefficients in the frequency domain. Fig. 2 shows a
> 256-point Hamming window and its frequency-domain
> counterpart . We can observe that has only 3
> significant coefficients, while the rest of them are close to zero.
> The convolution operation can be implemented using a 3-tap
> FIR filter in the frequency domain. Further the filter is symmetric,
> i.e., two of the filter coefficients are equal. Therefore,
> the convolution operation can be implemented using 2 multiplication
> and 2 addition operations. Table I shows the number of
> non-zero coefficients in frequency domain for different window
> functions used in the PSD computation. It may be noted that
> the use of a short FIR filter in frequency domain is the key to
> the derivation of the low-complexity PSD computation.

My main question is, how do I calculate the filter coefficients for the proposed filter?

I have tried calculating the Fourier transform of the hamming window and using those coefficients, however this did not give the result I was expecting. I will post both my Matlab code and resulting graphs below. I would expect the three plots to be (roughly) the same, but if that is a false assumption, please let me know.

(I did see the scaling of my Welch implementation is different from the built-in Matlab function, I will have a look at that)

Thank you in advance!

```
clearvars
% close all

%% Set variables
b_efficient = [1.35358 0.576525 0.576525];

%% Test signal
fs = 500;
dt = 1/fs;
stop_time = 2;

t = (0:dt:stop_time-dt)';
x = sin(2*pi*2*t) + 0.5 * sin(2*pi*6*t) + 0.25 * sin(2*pi*9*t) + 0.2 * sin(2*pi*15*t) + 0.1 * sin(2*pi*40*t);

%% Set variables
Nx = length(x);
nsc = floor(Nx/5);
nov = floor(nsc/2);
nff = max(256,2^nextpow2(nsc));

%% Divide input signal
start_index = 1;
end_index = start_index + nsc - 1;
index = 1;

while(start_index + nov < Nx)
    x_split{index} = x(start_index:end_index);
    
    index = index + 1;
    start_index = start_index + nov;
    end_index = start_index + nsc - 1;
end

%% Matlab Welch method
[psd_matlab, f_matlab] = pwelch(x,hamming(nsc), nov, nff, fs);

%% Manually apply Welch
for i=1:length(x_split)
    for j = 1:length(x_split{i})
        multiplier = 0.54 - (0.46 * cos(2 * pi * ((j-1)/(nsc-1)) ));     % Calculate beforehand
        x_windowed{i}(j,1) = x_split{i}(j) * multiplier;
    end
end
    
psd = zeros(nff / 2 + 1, 1);
for i = 1:length(x_split)
    power = abs(fft(x_windowed{i}, nff));
    psd = psd + ( 2 * power(1:nff/2 + 1).^2 );
end

psd = psd/(fs * sum(hamming(nsc).^2));

delta_f = fs / nsc;
f = 1:length(psd) * delta_f;

%% Efficient Welch
psd_efficient = zeros(nff / 2 + 1, 1);
for i = 1:length(x_split)
    power = abs(fft(x_split{i}, nff)).^2;
    power_filtered = filter_psd(power, b_efficient);
    psd_efficient = psd_efficient + power_filtered(1:nff/2 + 1);
end

psd_efficient = (2 * psd_efficient) / (fs * sum(hamming(nsc).^2));

%% Plot different PSD's
figure(2)
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(psd_matlab)
title("pwelch function matlab")
xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")

subplot(3,1,2)
plot(psd)
title("Own implementation")
xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")

subplot(3,1,3)
plot(psd_efficient)
title("efficient welch")
xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")

function [out] = filter_psd(in, b)
    out = zeros(size(in));
    for i = 1:length(in)
        if(i > 2)
            out(i) = b(1) * in(i) + b(2) * in(i - 1) + b(3) * in(i - 2);
        elseif(i == 2)
            out(i) = b(1) * in(i) + b(2) * in(i - 1);
        else
            out(i) = b(1) * in(i);
        end
    end
end
```

[image]
<sup>1</sup> Parhi, K. K., & Ayinala, M. (2014). Low-Complexity Welch Power Spectral Density Computation